# Declare variable inside String.format in c#

Tags: c#, variables, declare

How can i declare a variable inside String.format and use it again like :

```
String.Format("{0} {1}", int t = 1, new string[] { "a", "b" }.ElementAt(t));
```

**update**
I just want to learn something new and type the code in one line.
It is not necessary in this case, but useful in others.

**update**
I found another solution :

```
int indx;
var st = String.Format("{0} {1}", (indx=1), new string[] { "a", "b" }.ElementAt(indx));
```

Comment: What's the need for doing this? You can always declare the variable outside of string.Format and use the value inside string.Format.

Comment: is there a reason you think this would be a good idea?

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
I just want to learn something new and type the code in one line.
It is not necessary in this case, but used in other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good if you would share reason why you try to do it this way, and maybe tell us what are you working on.

Your code to work should look like this

```
int t = 1;
string[] myArray = new string[] { "a", "b" };
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", t, myArray[t]));
```

What you are attempting to do seems to be without any sense, first of all it will not work. Doing stuff your way makes it impossible to access **t** and **array** you created and even if it worked it would be same as static string `string myString = "1 b"`. Your way you make it impossible to manipulate these variables because they would only exist in context of that one line and would be back to their initial value when it gets executed each time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I just want to learn something new and type the code in one line.
It is not necessary in this case, but used in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Consider string.format as a method with few overloads, which takes few set of parameters as mentioned in [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx). Your way of calling the method does not satisfy your intent hence it would fail. 
I don't understand any reason why you would try to do something like this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I just want to learn something new and type the code in one line.
It is not necessary in this case, but used in other cases.